# In android studio the image not showing in the Display section even after importing

Tags: android, imageview

i am trying to show the picture, so that i use image view. in the image view xml section i wrote this code:

[image: XML source code]

Comment: Please don't take pictures of your code. Just copy-paste the actual code here and use the `{ }` button (or indent with 4 spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Dash) in image name. so please rename your image name from "dollar-png-dollar-png-transparent-image-1314" to "dollar_png_dollar_png_transparent_image_1314" and it will work. Here i attached a screenshot where you can see naming conventions in red alert to create image name in android studio.[image]